# Formatting newlfm document: (1) top alignment, and (2) disappearing margin

Tags: newlfm

I'm attempting to format a letter using the newlfm class. I have two questions:

1. How do I align the top of the body text on first page with the margin text?
2. How do I generate margin text to appear on the second and subsequent pages?

Here is a minimal working example that shows the problems I'm encountering:

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlfmP{busletternofrom,noLines,nolines,dateskipbefore=0in}

\leftmarginskipleft{0.5in}
\leftmarginskipright{0.25in}
\rightmarginsize{1in}

\nameto{John Doe}
\addrto{P.O.~Box 1000 \\ Athens, AK 11111}
\namefrom{Mary Moe}
\closeline{Regards,}
\greetto{Dear Sir or Madam:}

\newsavebox{\Lfirstpagelet}
\sbox{\Lfirstpagelet}{%
  \parbox[t]{1.75in}{%
    \raggedleft
    \printnamefrom}}

\newsavebox{\Lpagelet}
\sbox{\Lpagelet}{%
  \parbox[t]{1.75in}{%
    \raggedleft
    Page \thepage}}

\Lmargin{\usebox{\Lfirstpagelet}}
\lmargin{\usebox{\Lfirstpagelet}}


\begin{document}
  \begin{newlfm}

    \PhrRe{This is a test}

    \Blindtext[5]

  \end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Notice that on the first page, "Mary Moe" and the date are not vertically aligned. I would like them to be.

Notice also that on the second page, nothing appears in the left margin. I would like something to appear there (ideally with the page number).

EDIT: Here's a mockup of what I hope the end result will be.[image: Mock-Up]

Comment: I'd advice against [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm). Can you provide a visual (perhaps using some other word processing software like MS Word) of what your expected output should look like?

Comment: I've added a mockup. I prefer a solution using newlfm because of its other features, but I would also be interested in your thoughts on the best way to generate similar output using other classes/packages.

Comment: What other features?

Comment: I would also like to use the letter database features described in the `newlfm` [manual](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm/manual.pdf) in Section 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the default `article` class instead of trying to "make things work" with [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm).

The example below uses the following:

- Default `article` class
- [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for adjusting the text block dimensions
- [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) for placing the `Page X` page number from page two onward to the left of the top-left corner of the text block
- [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) to provide a way of writing one letter with multiple senders/recipients (and whatever else is needed) in line with the "letter database features" offered by `newlfm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,datatool}
% Set up your database of mail merge content (in CSV)
\begin{filecontents*}{mail_merge.csv}
letternum, fromperson, toperson, toaddress
1, Mary Moe, John Doe, PO Box 1000 \\ {Athens, AK 11111}
2, Jane Doe, Rumplestiltskin, Castle ABC \\ {Neverland, NL 54321}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\sloppy% Just for this example

% Set up your document layout
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=2in,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic}% Used to place the page number

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent
\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt}% Big skip between paragraphs

% Placement of the page number...
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    \ifnum\value{page}>1 % ...only on pages 2, 3, ...
      \raisebox{-.85\baselineskip}{\makebox[0pt][r]{Page \thepage~~~}}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\pagestyle{empty}% Don't place anything in the header/footer

% Load the mail merge database
\DTLloaddb[keys={letternum,fromperson,toperson,toaddress}]{mailmerge}{mail_merge.csv}

% Extract a record of choice...
\DTLassign{mailmerge}{2}% ... like record 2 in this case
  {\letternum=letternum,\fromperson=fromperson,\toperson=toperson,\toaddress=toaddress}

\begin{document}

\makebox[0pt][r]{\fromperson~~~}%
\today

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{} l}
  \toperson \\
  \toaddress
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Dear Sir or Madam:

\bigskip

\lipsum[1-6]

\bigskip

Regards,

\vspace{4\baselineskip}

\fromperson

\end{document}
```

Since addresses may have commas in them, `{`brace`}` the content that should fall under the same heading.

Comment: Thank you! This solution answers my question directly. Do you have any suggestions if the margin text (in this case the letter author on page 1 and the page number) should run more than one line?

Comment: @J.King: Sure. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd64S.png) was produced using [this paste](https://pastebin.com/1X9iv5Gg). Setting the margin content in a `[t]`op-aligned `tabular` is one way of achieving this. It may depend on what you want to place there and how many lines, but it's doable.